# How to fix a broken appclip link? appclip popup has no text & image

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, mobile-application, apple-appclips

I have an app with appclip, which suddenly stopped working - when I try to open the link I get this blurry image:

which looks as if it's loading, but it's not.

I checked the app's DOMAIN STATUS on **appstoreconnect** and it's green & valid.

any ideas anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

apparently it was a local problem - rebooting my iPhone solved it.